# asp.net library to access android file system

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, sqlite

I am creating a proof-of-concept web app that connects to a mainframe database, creates a SQLite database on an Android device and copies data from a table on the mainframe to a table on the Android device.  Is there a simple technique for addressing the Android file system directly from the web app, that doesn't require a third-party product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that would be lovely if web applications could just modify your local files. But unfortunately (for hackers), security prevents that. If you want to modify the file system automatically, you need to write an app and it needs to have the necessary permissions.

So in short, no, not possible from a web application.